# Convert $r^2\cos(2\theta)=9$ to Cartesian

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I need to convert $r^2\cos(2\theta)=9$ to Cartesian coordinates.
How should I do it?
What I did:
$$r^{2}\cos2\theta=r^{2}2\cos^{2}\theta-1=9\Rightarrow r^{2}\cos^{2}\theta=5\Rightarrow x^{2}=5$$
Did I'm right?
Thank you!!

Comment: Look closely at the equality $r^{2}\cos2\theta=r^{2}2\cos^{2}\theta-1$.  You have the right idea but have made a very careless error.

Comment: @David, can you tell me please what is the error? Thank you!!

Comment: @David, Ohh... I forgot the $()$. So it's: $r^2((2\cos^2\theta)-1)$...

Comment: That's it.  If you proceed carefully you should end up with $x^2-y^2=9$.

Comment: How did you get an $x^4$?

Comment: @David, my mistake.. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$r^2 \cos (2\theta ) =r^2 \cos^2 \theta  -r^2 \sin^2 \theta $$
but 
$$x=r\cos \theta , y=r\sin\theta $$ 
so we obtain $$x^2 -y^2 =9.$$